# Selenium WebDriver Very Slow to Append WebElement Data to List

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to store webelement content to a python list. While it works, it's taking ~15min to process ~2,000 rows.

```
# Grab webelements via xpath
rowt = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='table-body']/tr/th[@class='listing-title']")
rowl = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='table-body']/tr/td[@class='listing-location']")
rowli = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody[@class='table-body']/tr/th/a")

title = []
location = []
link = []

# Add webElement strings to lists
print('Compiling list...')
[title.append(i.text) for i in rowt]
[location.append(i.text) for i in rowl]
[link.append(i.get_attribute('href')) for i in rowli]
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: One way to do it is to send some Javascript browser-side to extract the data from the table. The Java webdriver bindings provide a versatile `executeJavascript` method https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- that lets you do that. Here's an example https://medium.com/@danidiaz/extracting-the-contents-of-a-table-in-selenium-ba69b2ca80a9 The corresponding function in Python seems to be `execute_script(script, *args)` but it's not clear from the docs how results are deserialized.

Comment: An example of Javascript injection in the browser from Python: https://johnpauljanecek.github.io/using-javascript-with-python-selenium/

Comment: Can you share the site? I would be interested in trying a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions (apologies if it’s not helpful):

1. I think Pandas can be used to load HTML tables directly. If your intent is to scrape a table then libraries like Bs4 also might come handy.
2. You can store the entire HTML and the parse it using Regex,cause all the data you are extracting is gonna be enclosed in fixed set of HTML tags.

Comment: I would use bs4, but website is dynamically loaded with javascript :(
I'll try the regex approach to see if it improves performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your solution is parsing through the table three times, once for the titles, once for the locations, and once for the links.

Try parsing the table just once.  Have a selector for the row, then loop through the rows, and for each row, extract the 3 elements using a relative path, e.g. for the link, it would look like this:

```
link.append(row.find_elements_by_xpath("./th/a").get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: This really isn't significantly different than what OP is already doing. You are still scraping the page again in your loops, you are just starting at an existing element.

Comment: I admit that I didn't do any timings.  It's just my gut feeling from experience that this would take a shorter time for Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, if the server that is presenting the page has an API, it would likely be significantly faster for you to use that to retrieve the data, rather than scraping the content from the page.

You could use the browser tools to see what the different requests are being sent to the server, and perhaps the data is being returned in a JSON form that you can easily retrieve your data from.

This, of course, assumes that you're interested in the data, not in verifying the content of the page directly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the slowest one is `[location.append(i.text) for i in rowl]`. 
When you call `i.text`, Selenium needs to determine what will be displayed in that element, so it needs more time to process. 
You can use a workaround `i.get_attribute('innerText')` instead.

```
[location.append(i.get_attribbute('innerText')) for i in rowl]
```

However, I can't guarantee that the result will be the same. (It should be the same or similar to `.Text`).

I've tested this on my machines with ~2000 row, `i.text` took 80 sec. while `i.get_attribute('innerText')` took 28 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Using bs4 would definitely help.
Even if you may have to find elements again using bs4, it was still faster to use bs4.
I'd like to suggest you try bs4.

I.e., code like this would work

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
elements = soup.find_all(...)
Loop using i
    Some job using elements[i]['target attribute']
```